# Select query for two different dates using vba

Tags: excel, vba, oracle, automation

[Input sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8AeL.png)

[recordset data fetched through sql query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1e45F.png)

I am trying to fetch implied data from oracle using odbc connection through excel vba for two different dates (actually the sql query takes the average of last 92 days of implied vols for multiple underlyings, so running it simultaneously for two different dates is not possible). hence i have mentioned the dates in two different cells [R4](one for implied vol today and another one [S4]for implied vol last week). to accomplish this i have created two sheets 
1) Sheets("UPDATER") - this is where the input Underlyings are placed with desired dates and data needs to copied in column U:Y
2) sheets("Data") - this is where the record set paste the results from the query then i have used vlookup to paste it again to updater sheet (column U:Y)

Where i am lacking?
1) i am able to pull the details for the date mentioned in cell R4 using the below code but how should i do it for another date ? should i rewrite the same code with just a different range? is there a shortcut

2) in case the query doesnt give result for any particular underlyier in that case i dont need the underlyier name to be #NA, the final result should always reflect All the underlying names given under column N and should reflect #NA under column X or Y, if implied vol is missing.

```
Public DBConn As ADODB.Connection

Public Sub createconn()

Dim UserId, Password As String
Set DBConn = New ADODB.Connection
Server = "*****"
UserId = "N******"
Password = "******"
With DBConn
    .CommandTimeout = 30
    .Open "PROVIDER=MSDASQL;" & _
    "DRIVER={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};" & _
    "SERVER=" & Server & ";" & _
    "UID=" & UserId & ";PWD=" & Password & ";"
End With

End Sub

Sub Get_implied()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim DBresults As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sqlquery As String, wsData As Worksheet, Datasht As Worksheet
Dim elr As Long
Dim lRow As Long
Set DBresults = New ADODB.Recordset

Set wsData = Worksheets("UPDATER")
Set Datasht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Worksheets("UPDATER").Range("U5:Y5", Range("U5").End(xlDown)).clear
Datasht.Cells.ClearContents
lRow = wsData.Cells(Rows.count, 14).End(xlUp).Row
'Mainsheet.Range("B7:B15").ClearContents
If lRow > 1 Then

    Call createconn

    sqlquery = "select distinct p.asof, idvalue as UL ,i.Pkey , round(avg(p.impliedvol) over (partition by id.idvalue),8)as AvgVolsToday" & vbNewLine & _
"from (select * from ***** where type in ( 'Equity' ,'EquityIdx')) I" & vbNewLine & _
"inner join ****** o on o.underlying = i.pkey" & vbNewLine & _
"inner join ****** id on i.ids = id.idset" & vbNewLine & _
"inner join ***** p on p.***** = o.pkey" & vbNewLine & _
"where id.idtype = 'RIC'" & vbNewLine & _
"and o.type = 'Option'" & vbNewLine & _
"and o.iscurrent = 'Y'" & vbNewLine & _
"and o.issuesize is null" & vbNewLine & _
"and p.asof = '" & Format(wsData.Range("R4").value, "ddmmmyy") & "'" & vbenewline & _
"and o.enddate <= p.asof +92" & vbNewLine & _
"and p.strike = 100" & vbNewLine & _
"and p.putcall = 'C'" & vbNewLine & _
"and p.service = 'D'" & vbNewLine & _
"and id.idvalue in ("

    For i = 2 To lRow
        sqlquery = sqlquery & "'" & wsData.Range("N" & i).value & "',"
    Next i
    sqlquery = left(sqlquery, Len(sqlquery) - 1) & ")"
    DBresults.Open sqlquery, DBConn, adOpenDynamic
    If Not DBresults.EOF Then Datasht.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset DBresults

    elr = Worksheets("Data").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    elr1 = Worksheets("UPDATER").Cells(Rows.count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
    If elr > 1 Then
        wsData.Range("U5").FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(Data!C[-20],MATCH(UPDATER!R[-3]C[-7],Data!C[-19],0),0)"
        wsData.Range("U5").AutoFill Destination:=Range("U5:U" & elr1)
        wsData.Range("V5").FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(Data!C[-20],MATCH(UPDATER!R[-3]C[-8],Data!C[-20],0),0)"
        wsData.Range("V5").AutoFill Destination:=Range("V5:V" & elr1)
        wsData.Range("W5").FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(Data!C[-20],MATCH(UPDATER!R[-3]C[-9],Data!C[-21],0),0)"
        wsData.Range("W5").AutoFill Destination:=Range("W5:W" & elr1)
        wsData.Range("X5").FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(Data!C[-20],MATCH(UPDATER!R[-3]C[-10],Data!C[-22],0),0)"
        wsData.Range("X5").AutoFill Destination:=Range("X5:X" & elr1)
        Range("U5:X" & elr).Copy
        Range("U5:X" & elr).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False


    End If


    End If


Set DBresults = Nothing
Call close_conn
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub



Sub close_conn()

DBConn.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: sure. done. i am a rookie here

Comment: I am just a novice in SQL-VBA. But one can start learning [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OWKae1pTTnE&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5&index=96)

Comment: Thanks gor that link. however i am able to connect to oracle database using vba. i am little skeptical how do i do it for two different dates.

Comment: can anyone please help ?